# How to create rows in gridview based on user input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rows

I want to create rows for the gridview based on user input e.g months enter then it will create gridview rows based on user input.  dont know if its correct to use a for loop in the row adding field.

````
   protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                double Amt, Months;
                Amt = Convert.ToDouble(ILoanAmount);
                Months = Convert.ToDouble(IRepaymentRate);
                calc.Calculator(Amt, Months);
                double Intrest, MonthlyInstallment;
                double Rate = 0.07;
                Intrest = Math.Round(Amt * Months * Rate,2);
                MonthlyInstallment = Math.Round(Amt / ((Math.Pow(1 + Rate, Months) - 1) / (Rate * Math.Pow(1 + Rate, Months))),2);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { new DataColumn("Period/Month", typeof(double)),
                            new DataColumn("Periodic Payment", typeof(double)),
                            new DataColumn("Intrest Payment", typeof(double)),
                            new DataColumn("Principal Payment", typeof(double)),
                            new DataColumn("Principal Balance",typeof(double)) });
            dt.Rows.Add(
               for (int i = 0; i < Months; i++)
            {
              //something like here i dont know if its correct if i should use a for loop inside here
            }
                    );
                GridBal.DataSource = dt;
                GridBal.DataBind();
        }

    }```
````

Comment: I would do it the other way.  For loop based on your ````Months```` count, and then inside each iteration you add a new Row to your ````dt```` object.  And where is the user input at? Do you need to loop through some sets of controls to get the data (i.e. from a textbox) to create these rows?

Comment: Could you please help me with the code i don't understand it please? I am a newbie to c# development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here.... I wrote something very similar to yours that you should be able to use to adapt to what you need.  `row[0]` lines up to the Period/Month column, `row[1]` to the Periodic Payment column, etc...

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] { new DataColumn("Period/Month", typeof(double)),
                            new DataColumn("Periodic Payment", typeof(double)),
                            new DataColumn("Intrest Payment", typeof(double)),
                            new DataColumn("Principal Payment", typeof(double)),
                            new DataColumn("Principal Balance",typeof(double)) });

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = "1";
            row[1] = "2";
            row[2] = "3";
            row[3] = "4";
            row[4] = "5";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```